# Quartz.NET with AdoNetJobStore performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, quartz.net

I have ~5M Jobs and each Job has exactly one Trigger scheduled in Quartz.Net, as a maximum ~300K Jobs scheduled to run at same time, I have a constraint to proceed all 300K Jobs within 3 hours (so ~100K Jobs/Hour), but now my test app is able to proceed only 10K per hour when Quartz.Net is configured to use AdoNetJobStore.

I'm using next Quartz config:

```
<quartz>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="XxxDefaultQuartzScheduler" />
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceId" value="instance_one" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="1" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="default" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="false" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.connectionStringName" value="QuartzDbContext" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.provider" value="SqlServer-20" />
</quartz>
```

Is it possible to configure Quartz.Net with SQL Job Store to provide such performance?

Comment: Sorry, config file has next connection string:         <add name="QuartzDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=quartz_test;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Quartz causes quite a bit of contention on its database tables when it tries to pick a job. This gets worse if jobs are very quick and you use many threads to try to pick jobs - it results in many threads frequently trying to access the Quartz tables for locking. Do you need to schedule these jobs or do you need to queue them? If you need a queue (as opposed to scheduled jobs), you're better off not using Quartz.

Comment: The task is to proceed them all at certain time (and as there is too many jobs I could have 3 hours to complete with them). I think about using one job that will start at this time and query my custom table with job info and processing them, but then I caught myself on that I'm re-implementing Quartz functionality: misfire strategy, schedule, triggers and crash recovery.

Answer (score 8):

The default thread count of 10 is quite low for this kind of massive usage. I'd increment it to something like, say, 25 x cores in computer. You can naturally test higher values too. Modern hardware should be able to handle 100-200 threads, but thread contention may come as an issue.

You didn't mention the version you are using, but with newer versions you can drop the *quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type* , it's use optimized row locking when it detects that SQL Server is used. Always use the latest version (when possible), latest tends to be most optimized and bug-free.

After Quartz configuration is tweaked, you naturally must profile your own job code. Say your code would be able to complete in 5 seconds so what we would approximately have is:

**5 seconds * 300 000 triggers / 100 threads => 15 000 seconds ~  250 minutes ~ 4 hours**

Lower that five seconds of execution time to three and you'll be hitting the 2h 30m mark. Or just raise the amount of threads and be prepared for some battle of resources - depends on what your jobs are doing and how.

Another consideration could be clustering, run multiple workers against Quartz database if the database isn't the bottleneck.