# Quartz.Net Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore Usage

Tags: quartz.net

I cannot seem to find good documentation around using this for the quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type setting within the quartz config.  We are using SQL Server and the documentation says it's used for SQL Server to lock rows.  I see it used in most examples in searching online.

I see mention in this thread around it not being required in newer versions, but not a lot of detail: [Quartz.NET with AdoNetJobStore performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367373/quartz-net-with-adonetjobstore-performance)

Should I include this?  I get a warning logged that states it is less efficient, but I'd rather it be less efficient than have synchronization issues.  We have some cases where we are running clustered and some where we aren't.  It would be good to know if we should set this in both scenarios or not as well.

Answer (score 0):

We're using Quartz.NET (3.0.3),Sql Server and multiple scheduler instance and our properties just like this ;

[Same Quartz.Net scheduler in multiple app server.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175092/same-quartz-net-scheduler-in-multiple-app-server)

And yes documentation is not good enough for us :(